# how to fit a windowed output to a widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to fit a separate dialog window into my PyQT GUI. I have the camera feed in a separate window, but the stats pop up in another separate window.  I wish to get it into my application next to the camera feed so it is all in one. It is the section labeled emotional probabilities.

here is the GUI application main window:

[image]

Here is my code that I have tried thus far with no success (ImgWidget_3 is the Emotional probability group box/container in the pyqt designer .ui file ):

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model

# parameters for loading data and images
detection_model_path = '/xxxxxxx/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
emotion_model_path = '/xxxxxxx/_mini_XCEPTION.102-0.66.hdf5'

# hyper-parameters for bounding boxes shape
# loading models
face_detection = cv2.CascadeClassifier(detection_model_path)
emotion_classifier = load_model(emotion_model_path, compile=False)
EMOTIONS = ["angry" ,"disgust","scared", "happy", "sad", "surprised",
 "neutral"]


running = False
capture_thread = None
form_class = uic.loadUiType("simple.ui")[0]
q = Queue.Queue()


def grab(cam, queue, width, height, fps):
    global running
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(cam)
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, fps)

    while(running):
        frame = {}        
        capture.grab()
        retval, img = capture.retrieve(0)
        frame["img"] = img

        if queue.qsize() < 10:
            queue.put(frame)
        else:
            print queue.qsize()

class OwnImageWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(OwnImageWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.image = None

    def setImage(self, image):
        self.image = image
        sz = image.size()
        self.setMinimumSize(sz)
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        if self.image:
            qp.drawImage(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0), self.image)
        qp.end()

class StatImageWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(StatImageWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.image = None

    def setImage(self, image):
        self.image = image
        sz = image.size()
        self.setMinimumSize(sz)
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        if self.image:
            qp.drawImage(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0), self.image)
        qp.end()



class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start_clicked)

        self.window_width = self.ImgWidget.frameSize().width()
        self.window_height = self.ImgWidget.frameSize().height()
        self.ImgWidget = OwnImageWidget(self.ImgWidget)

        self.ImgWidget_3 = StatImageWidget(self.ImgWidget_3)


        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_frame)
        self.timer.start(1)


    def start_clicked(self):
        global running
        running = True
        capture_thread.start()
        self.startButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.startButton.setText('Starting...')


    def update_frame(self):
        if not q.empty():
            self.startButton.setText('Camera is live')
            frame = q.get()
            img = frame["img"]

            img_height, img_width, img_colors = img.shape
            scale_w = float(self.window_width) / float(img_width)
            scale_h = float(self.window_height) / float(img_height)
            scale = min([scale_w, scale_h])

            if scale == 0:
                scale = 1

            img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=scale, fy=scale, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            height, width, bpc = img.shape
            bpl = bpc * width
            image = QtGui.QImage(img.data, width, height, bpl, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
            self.ImgWidget.setImage(image)

            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            faces = face_detection.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.1,minNeighbors=5,minSize=(30,30),flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)

            canvas = np.zeros((250, 300, 3), dtype="uint8")
            frameClone = frame.copy()
            if len(faces) > 0:
                faces = sorted(faces, reverse=True,
                key=lambda x: (x[2] - x[0]) * (x[3] - x[1]))[0]
                (fX, fY, fW, fH) = faces
                            # Extract the ROI of the face from the grayscale image, resize it to a fixed 28x28 pixels, and then prepare
                    # the ROI for classification via the CNN
                roi = gray[fY:fY + fH, fX:fX + fW]
                roi = cv2.resize(roi, (64, 64))
                roi = roi.astype("float") / 255.0
                roi = img_to_array(roi)
                roi = np.expand_dims(roi, axis=0)


                preds = emotion_classifier.predict(roi)[0]
                emotion_probability = np.max(preds)
                label = EMOTIONS[preds.argmax()]


                for (i, (emotion, prob)) in enumerate(zip(EMOTIONS, preds)):
                        # construct the label text
                        text = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(emotion, prob * 100)

                        # draw the label + probability bar on the canvas
                       # emoji_face = feelings_faces[np.argmax(preds)]


                        w = int(prob * 300)
                        cv2.rectangle(canvas, (7, (i * 35) + 5),
                        (w, (i * 35) + 35), (0, 0, 255), -1)
                        cv2.putText(canvas, text, (10, (i * 35) + 23),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45,
                        (255, 255, 255), 2)
                        cv2.putText(img, label, (fX, fY - 10),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                        cv2.rectangle(img, (fX, fY), (fX + fW, fY + fH),
                                      (0, 0, 255), 2)


        cv2.imshow("Emotional Probabilities", canvas)
        cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')
        self.ImgWidget_3.canvas(imshow)


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        global running
        running = False


capture_thread = threading.Thread(target=grab, args = (0, q, 1920, 1080, 30))

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MyWindowClass(None)
w.setWindowTitle('Test app')
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

How can I make this successfully work?

Comment: You could share the other files needed to launch your application through github or similar

Comment: share your .ui file

Comment: I am uploading the files to github.... mu internet  is very slow (I am not in the United States). As soon as it uploads I will share the links.

Comment: In America, the internet is extremely fast and darn near 100% reliable. When I decided to move abroad and live overseas for the rest of my life, I am finding that the internet in the place I am at is - shall we say - extremely weak and terrible AT BEST! LOL!  The upload has failed several times. can I just paste the project files here??

Comment: If you can then do it, if the files weigh a lot first zipped and then upload it to somewhere like drive, dropbox, etc and share the link.

Comment: here is the link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1w8LOzlVy77DHZ9PbT6SizRZMST-YkBbl?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea in this case is to convert the numpy array to QImage and place it in the widget, on the other hand it is not necessary to have a custom widget, you can use a QLabel so change the .ui. And finally your implementation froze the GUI which is not pleasant for the user so improve your implementation by sending the information through signals and using QThread.

**simple.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1000</width>
    <height>610</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="2">
     <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
      <property name="title">
       <string>Emotion Probabilities</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="emotional_label">
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="startButton">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>0</width>
        <height>50</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Start</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
      <property name="title">
       <string>Video</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="video_label">
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1000</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**simpleMultifaceGUI_v01.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

import cv2
import numpy as np
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from keras.engine.saving import load_model
from keras_preprocessing.image import img_to_array

__author__ = "Ismail ibn Thomas-Benge"
__copyright__ = "Copyright 2018, blackstone.software"
__version__ = "0.1"
__license__ = "GPL"

# parameters for loading data and images
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
detection_model_path = os.path.join("haarcascade_files/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
emotion_model_path = os.path.join("models/_mini_XCEPTION.102-0.66.hdf5")

# hyper-parameters for bounding boxes shape
# loading models
face_detection = cv2.CascadeClassifier(detection_model_path)
emotion_classifier = load_model(emotion_model_path, compile=False)
EMOTIONS = ["angry", "disgust", "scared", "happy", "sad", "surprised", "neutral"]

emotion_classifier._make_predict_function()

running = False
capture_thread = None
form_class, _ = uic.loadUiType("simple.ui")


def NumpyToQImage(img):
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    qimg = QtGui.QImage(rgb.data, rgb.shape[1], rgb.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
    return qimg


class CaptureWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    imageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self, properties, parent=None):
        super(CaptureWorker, self).__init__(parent)
        self._running = False
        self._capture = None
        self._properties = properties

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        if self._capture is None:
            self._capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self._properties["index"])
            self._capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, self._properties["width"])
            self._capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, self._properties["height"])
            self._capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, self._properties["fps"])
        self._running = True
        self.doWork()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def stop(self):
        self._running = False

    def doWork(self):
        while self._running:
            self._capture.grab()
            ret, img = self._capture.retrieve(0)
            if ret:
                self.imageChanged.emit(img)
        self._capture.release()
        self._capture = None


class ProcessWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    resultsChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
    imageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
    def process_image(self, img):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_detection.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30),
                                                flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
        canvas = np.zeros((250, 300, 3), dtype="uint8")
        if len(faces) > 0:
            face = sorted(faces, reverse=True, key=lambda x: (x[2] - x[0]) * (x[3] - x[1]))[0]
            (fX, fY, fW, fH) = face
            roi = gray[fY:fY + fH, fX:fX + fW]
            roi = cv2.resize(roi, (64, 64))
            roi = roi.astype("float") / 255.0
            roi = img_to_array(roi)
            roi = np.expand_dims(roi, axis=0)
            preds = emotion_classifier.predict(roi)[0]
            label = EMOTIONS[preds.argmax()]
            cv2.putText(img, label, (fX, fY - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (fX, fY), (fX+fW, fY+fH), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            self.imageChanged.emit(img)

            for i, (emotion, prob) in enumerate(zip(EMOTIONS, preds)):
                text = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(emotion, prob * 100)
                w = int(prob * 300)
                cv2.rectangle(canvas, (7, (i * 35) + 5),
                              (w, (i * 35) + 35), (0, 0, 255), -1)
                cv2.putText(canvas, text, (10, (i * 35) + 23),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45,
                            (255, 255, 255), 2)
                cv2.putText(img, label, (fX, fY - 10),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                cv2.rectangle(img, (fX, fY), (fX + fW, fY + fH),
                              (0, 0, 255), 2)
                self.resultsChanged.emit(canvas)


class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindowClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self._thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self._thread.start()
        self._capture_obj = CaptureWorker({"index": 0, "width": 640, "height": 480, "fps": 30})
        self._process_obj = ProcessWorker()
        self._capture_obj.moveToThread(self._thread)
        self._process_obj.moveToThread(self._thread)
        self._capture_obj.imageChanged.connect(self._process_obj.process_image) 
        self._process_obj.imageChanged.connect(self.on_video_changed)
        self._process_obj.resultsChanged.connect(self.on_emotional_changed)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start_clicked(self):
        QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self._capture_obj, "start", QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.startButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.startButton.setText('Starting...')

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
    def on_emotional_changed(self, im):
        img = NumpyToQImage(im)
        pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img)
        self.emotional_label.setFixedSize(pix.size())
        self.emotional_label.setPixmap(pix)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
    def on_video_changed(self, im):
        img = NumpyToQImage(im)
        pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img)
        self.video_label.setPixmap(pix.scaled(self.video_label.size()))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._capture_obj.stop()
        self._thread.quit()
        self._thread.wait()
        super(MyWindowClass, self).closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindowClass()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks @ellanesc. The facial recognition box that shows up around the face is missing. Any ideas how to get that back??

Comment: I just added it in the original question. Thanks

Comment: but as you can see from the screen shot I posted from my original  code. That is indeed what appears when I run the original code. I need that feature. without it - the application is useless ...

Comment: @ironmantis7x I already added it, have you tried my updated code?

Comment: yes! i just did (i just saw your updated code). That fixes it. Thank you so much. I accept your answer.

Comment: bounty assigned